# How can I use Realsense SR300

Tags: ros, realsense

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm Japanese, so maybe my English is strange.
Now, I want to use Intel Realsense SR300.
I write my environment and please teach me what should I tell you about my PC because I'm beginner.
OS : Ubuntu14.04
ROS ; Indigo
Senser : RealsenseSR300
Kernel : 4.4.0-040400-generic

I write all commands I did.

$: sudo apt-get -y install libusb-1.0-0-dev git build-essential

$: git clone https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense

$: cd librealsense

$: git checkout tags/v0.9.2

$: scripts/install_glfw3.sh

$: make

$: sudo make install

$: sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo

$: sudo cp config/99-realsense-libusb.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/

$: sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

$: udevadm trigger

$: ./bin/cpp-capture

Then I have an error,

RealSense error calling rs_create_context(api_version:4):
API version mismatch: librealsense.so was compiled with API version 1.12.1 but the application was compiled with 4! Make sure correct version of the library is installed (make install)

I installed "Docker" and I checked "client API version: 1.18".
What should I do??
Thank you.

Edit: Improved readability

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262583/how-can-i-use-realsense-sr300/) by [ant0520](https://answers.ros.org/users/30455/ant0520/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-05-26**:
Looks like you have two different versions of librealsense on your system. Please paste output of dpkg -l | grep realsense

**Comment by [ant0520](https://answers.ros.org/users/30455/ant0520/) on 2017-05-28**:
Thank you your comment!
I did that command and I past the result!
$: dpkg -l | grep realsense
ii  ros-indigo-librealsense                               1.12.1-1trusty-20170329-171250-0700                 amd64        Library for capturing data from the Intel(R) RealSense(TM) F200, SR300, R200, LR

**Comment by [thompson104](https://answers.ros.org/users/30900/thompson104/) on 2017-07-13**:
Hey, do yo get any luck doing that? I'm not sure how to use the files under the example folder. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have two different versions f the same library installed:

1. The version of the package ros-indigo-librealsense
2. The one that you compiled from source

What you are trying to do is running cpp-capture (source version) with the binary library from ubuntu. Uninstall either version.

---

Originally posted by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) with karma: 1504 on 2017-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ant0520](https://answers.ros.org/users/30455/ant0520/) on 2017-05-29**:
Thanks!!
I could connect SR300!!